# ERROR 00539: Error running expression:rcexec()

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I'm trying to run a batch operation on raster calculator. The expression I use is this:

```
(Float("92011033_B2.tif") - Float("92011033_B5.tif")) / (Float("92011033_B2.tif") + Float("92011033_B5.tif"))
```

And at the moment of executing it throws me the following error:

ERROR 00539: Error running expression: rcexec ().

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have entered your equation manually?

In ArcGIS 10.5 If I build this simple equation in the Raster Calculator tool this is what is submitted:

```
"Float("LE71370452001333SGS00_B5.TIF") - Float("LE71370452001333SGS00_B2.TIF")"
```

What is actually submitted and executed is this:

```
Float(Raster(r"LE71370452001333SGS00_B5.TIF")) - Float(Raster(r"LE71370452001333SGS00_B2.TIF"))
```

As you can see it encloses the raster names within Raster() which we are not seeing in your code.